# How to check if an entered value is 10 javascript?

Tags: javascript, verify

I want to check if an entered value is 10 or not(and if the value is 10, I want the result to be sent to "send.php"). What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php  $cod1=rand(0, 10); 
    $cod2=10-$cod1; ?>   
    <form action='send.php'  method='post' onsubmit='f1(this)'>
    Please enter the value of <br> <?php echo $cod1 ?> + <?php echo $cod2 ?> in the following box
    <input type="text" name="xrezultat" id="xrezultat" class="box" size="32"/>

    <input name="Submit1" type="submit" class="butt" value="Trimiteti">      
    <input name="Submit2" type="reset" class="butt" value="Stergeti ">

    </form>


    <Script> 
    function f1(input) 
    {    
    if(document.getElementById("xrezultat").value!=10)   
    aux==false;

     if (aux == true)
    {
       return true;
    }

       else
    {
        alert ( "Please enter the correct value" );
        return false;
                 }


    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Why does your function have an `input` parameter that is never used?

Answer (score 2):

`aux==false;` checks to see if `aux` is equal to false, it does not assign to it.

It should read `aux=false;`.

Comment: @Snuffleupageus Thank you very much ! and can I check somehow if the entered value is numeric, not string or char?

Comment: @euloli check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1830844/1090190) answer to validate numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `parseInt`.

```
var numberValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("xrezultat").value, 10);
```

Comment: `onsubmit='return f1(this)';` // return is missing, that matters or not ?

Comment: The string `"10"` is `==` to the int `10`. (this is not the case with `===`)

Comment: @Dev the problem was that I had 2 x "=" not only one as I should. It doesn't matter if I have return or not ...